# 1004 application defined or object defined error while using specialcells property

Tags: excel, vba

Following is the code snippet which helps in understanding the context of the problem. If Not(r is nothing) condition is true then i am getting 1004 error. The peculiar thing is if i run the code in debug mode step by step then error occurs for every 2nd time the condition is satisfied. Kindly help me fix this error. Thanks.

```
With wb.Sheets(csht)
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    firstCol = 1
    'If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then firstCol = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
End With

'countCol = lastCol - firstCol + 1
On Error Resume Next
If firstCol < lastCol Then
    Set r = wb.Sheets(csht).Range(wb.Sheets(csht).Cells(1, firstCol), wb.Sheets(csht).Cells(1, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Else
    Set r = wb.Sheets(csht).Range(wb.Sheets(csht).Cells(1, firstCol), wb.Sheets(csht).Cells(1, firstCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If Not (r Is Nothing) Then
    'On Error Resume Next
    With wb.Sheets(csht)
        If firstCol < lastCol Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, firstCol), .Cells(1, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
            .Range(.Cells(1, firstCol), .Cells(1, firstCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    End With
'Err.Clear
'On Error GoTo 0
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't look right: `.Range(.Cells(1, firstCol), .Cells(1, firstCol))` Shouldn't one of them be `lastCol`?

Comment: this statement is executed when firstCol=lastCol. I was getting some range overlap error in that situation.So else condition is inserted.The code there is actually '.Cells(1, firstCol)'(a mistake in the code posted) .Please ignore it as most of the time firstCol<LastCol in this context.

Comment: If you use `SpecialCells` on a one cell range, it actually applies to the entire worksheet - I don't think you want that!

Comment: oh...I didn't know that.Thanks.I'll use a simple if isempty condition there instead..But like i said that line is executed only when firstCol=LastCol which is very rare in this context. So the error still remains unresolved.

Comment: Did you declare r as a `Range`?

Comment: Yes, I declared r as Range

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, does `csht` change? You should reset r to Nothing in the If block, because `Specialcells` won't return Nothing if it errors, so r will still point to a range that you deleted.

Comment: Finally fixed it.When i set autofiltermode=False  and r to nothing for every iteration, everything is working fine.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` piece at all.  Since you are just deleting the entire column, you could change the code to this:

```
With wb.Sheets(csht)
If firstCol < lastCol Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, firstCol), .Cells(1, lastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    Else
        .Range(.Cells(1, firstCol), .Cells(1, firstCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I am deleting columns with blank headers. Please go through my code carefully.